# wxpython - Multiple TextEntryDialog windows

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to do a TextEntryDialog followed by another TextEntryDialog.  I can only get the first one to appear and then after I hit ok a second one does not appear.  I'm sure it's something easy, anyone have any suggestions?  Thanks.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import wx

class bucky(wx.Frame):    
    def __init__(self,parent,id):   
      wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'Frame aka window', size=(300,200))  
      panel = wx.Panel(self)   

      user = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, "Login", "Username", "")

      if user.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:   
        username = user.GetValue()   
        user.Destroy()   
        password = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, "Password", "Password", "")

if __name__ =='__main__':   
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()   
    frame = bucky(parent=None, id=-1)   
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `ShowModal` again to see your entry:

```
user = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, "Login", "Username", "")
if user.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
    print 'here'   
    password = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, "Password", "Password", "")
    if password.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:   
        print 'there'
```

Note you do not need to `destroy` the dialog

Comment: Well that was easy!  Thanks a lot (this was my first post, will definitely be back!)  I also found out I could use password.Show(True) and that works as well apparently.  Thanks again!