# How do I create a permanent text entry input on my main wxPython window?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm new to wxPython, and I was wondering if it's possible to create a text entry dialog input bar within the main window? Instead of having to create a new box/window for the user input, I'd like to have a permanent input field, like the class *resultsInput* provides for the PyQt QWidget layout.

I see that it's possible to create [Multiple TextEntryDialog windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912784/wxpython-multiple-textentrydialog-windows), but can we do this on a single window?

Is this possible using TextEntryDialog, or do I need to use a different class?

Here's what I have so far:

```
import wx

class Window(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'WX Python Window', size=(300, 200))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        text_enter = wx.TextEntryDialog(None, "Please enter some text.", "Title", "Default")
        if text_enter.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            response = text_enter.GetValue()
            wx.StaticText(panel, -1, response, (10, 50))

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = Window(parent=None, id=-1)
    frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering if it's possible to create a text entry dialog input bar

You seem to be a bit confused here.

A text entry input bar isn't a dialog. It's just a widget (aka control)—in particular, a [`TextCtrl`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.TextCtrl-class.html).

A `TextEntryDialog` includes a `TextCtrl`, and a title bar, and a caption, and some buttons; you don't want any of that except maybe a button or two. And it has a panel with some sizers to lay things out, but you don't want that; it doesn't even place the buttons alongside the entry bar. It's also a top-level window, which you again don't want. More importantly, it has a bunch of code to act like a dialog—to modally take over the entire interface and not return until the user has typed something and clicked a button—which you definitely don't want.

So, the only thing you want out of the dialog is that you want a `TextCtrl`, and a `Button`, probably organized together in a `Panel` with a `Sizer` so you can control the layout. So, just create those. Add a handler for the button that read's the text input's value and does something with it, and you're done.

(What you're specifically asking for, a way to place a dialog within the window, isn't possible; you can embed top-level windows into child windows, or you can create something that acts just like a dialog but isn't top-level. But neither of those is easy, and neither is what you want here.)

Comment: It looks like I'm confused, but I think it has more to do with me not knowing the lingo/terminology with which to ask the question. I'm still fairly new to coding, and especially OOP concepts.

How would you have worded the question differently?
Thanks again!

Comment: @Basper82: Good question, but it's hard for me to put myself in your shoes. The title is good. I guess the first paragraph should ask something like, "… to create a text entry input bar, like the one in a `TextEntryDialog`, but without the whole dialog, just within the main window"?

Comment: Also, since you seem to know some Qt terminology, trying to explain things in Qt terms might help. On the other hand, it might not; there are probably a lot of wx experts who don't know Qt at all, and you might just scare them away.

Answer (score 0):

here is something

```
import os
FPATH = os.path.expanduser("~/.my_username")
class SavedTextCtrl(wx.TextCtrl):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kw):
        self.save_action = kw.pop("save_action",lambda:open(FPATH,"wb").write(self.GetValue()))
        self.load_action = kw.pop("load_action",lambda:self.SetValue(
                                open(FPATH,"rb").read() if os.path.exists(FPATH) else "")
                            )
        wx.TextCtrl.__init__(self,*args,**kw)
        self.load_action()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT,lambda e:self.save_action())


class Window(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'WX Python Window', size=(300, 200))
        sz = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sz.Add(wx.StaticText(self,-1,"Name:"))
        self.text_ctrl = SavedTextCtrl(self,-1)
        sz.Add(self.text_ctrl)
        self.SetSizer(sz)
        self.Layout()
        self.Fit()
```

that might be sort of what you are looking for